# Flashlight app unable to activate flash

Tags: android, flash, flashlight

I have followed [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/04/android-developing-flashlight-application/) guide to create a simple flashlight app.  I removed some functionality (image changing, sound) from the app in an attempt to remove whatever issue is preventing the flashlight from coming on.

I am using a Nexus 5 running 4.4.2

Main activity:

```
package com.test.testFlashlight;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class testFlashlight extends Activity {
Button btnSwitch;

private Camera camera;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean hasFlash;
Parameters params;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_testFlashlight);

    // flash switch button
    btnSwitch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFlash);


    // First check if device is supporting flashlight or not
    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        // device doesn't support flash
        // Show alert message and close the application
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(testFlashlight.this)
                .create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // closing the application
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    }

    // get the camera
    getCamera();

    // displaying button image
    //toggleButtonImage();


    // Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
    btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Debug_point_1", "Flashlight evaluation if on");
            if (isFlashOn) {
                // turn off flash

                        // closing the application

                turnOffFlash();
            } else {
                // turn on flash
                turnOnFlash();
            }
        }
    });
}


// Get the camera
private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


// Turning On flash
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        //playSound();
        Log.d("Debug_point_2", "Turning flashlight on");
        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;
        Log.d("Debug_point_3", "Flashlight should be on");


        // changing button/switch image
        //toggleButtonImage();
    }

}


// Turning Off flash
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        // changing button/switch image
       //toggleButtonImage();
    }
}


// Playing sound
// will play button toggle sound on flash on / off
private void playSound(){/*
    if(isFlashOn){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.light_switch_off);
    }else{
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.light_switch_on);
    }
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    mp.start();*/
}

/*
 * Toggle switch button images
 * changing image states to on / off
 * */
private void toggleButtonImage(){

}
/*
    if(isFlashOn){
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_switch_on);
    }else{
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_switch_off);
    }*/


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // on pause turn off the flash
    turnOffFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // on resume turn on the flash
    if(hasFlash)
        turnOnFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // on starting the app get the camera params
    getCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // on stop release the camera
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.testFlashlight" >
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.testFlashlight.testFlashlight"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

activity_testFlashlight.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.test.testFlashlight.testFlashlight"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_testFlashlight.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.test.testFlashlight.testFlashlight$PlaceholderFragment">



<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Flashlight"
    android:id="@+id/btnFlash"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat section I think matters:

```
03-31 19:22:13.146     784-1192/? E/LocSvc_IzatApiV02? W/virtual int izat_core::IzatApiV02::injectLocation(GpsExtLocation):665]: error! inject position failed
03-31 19:22:13.156     784-1192/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02? W/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiV02::injectPosition(double, double, float):492]: error! status = eLOC_CLIENT_FAILURE_INVALID_PARAMETER, inject_pos_ind.status = UNKNOWN
03-31 19:22:13.806     184-1036/? I/AwesomePlayer? setDataSource_l(URL suppressed)
03-31 19:22:13.816      184-837/? D/audio_hw_primary? select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
03-31 19:22:13.846      784-865/? D/ConnectivityService? Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
03-31 19:22:13.866    1041-1041/? D/PhoneStatusBar? disable: < expand* icons alerts ticker* system_info back* home* recent* clock* search >
03-31 19:22:13.886      784-865/? D/ConnectivityService? Done.
03-31 19:22:13.886      784-865/? D/ConnectivityService? Setting timer for 720seconds
03-31 19:22:13.906     184-1036/? I/AwesomePlayer? setDataSource_l(URL suppressed)
03-31 19:22:13.906    2064-2064/? D/YouTube? apps.youtube.app.prefetch.f.onReceive:366 Received: android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
03-31 19:22:13.906    1244-2943/? D/NfcService? NFC-C ON
03-31 19:22:13.916    1366-1370/? D/dalvikvm? GC_CONCURRENT freed 657K, 5% free 18682K/19584K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 42ms
03-31 19:22:13.916    1366-1489/? D/dalvikvm? WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 26ms
03-31 19:22:13.926     184-1036/? I/Camera2ClientBase? Camera 0: Opened
03-31 19:22:13.936     184-1036/? E/mm-camera-intf? mm_camera_open: dev name = /dev/video1, cam_idx = 1
03-31 19:22:13.936      198-198/? E/mm-camera-sensor? module_sensor_start_session:577 session 1
03-31 19:22:13.936     784-1192/? E/LocSvc_IzatApiV02? W/virtual int izat_core::IzatApiV02::injectLocation(GpsExtLocation):665]: error! inject position failed
03-31 19:22:13.946      198-198/? E/mm-camera-sensor? eeprom_load_library:515 e_ctrl->eeprom_lib.func_tbl =0xb6b67004
03-31 19:22:13.946     784-1192/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02? W/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiV02::injectPosition(double, double, float):492]: error! status = eLOC_CLIENT_FAILURE_INVALID_PARAMETER, inject_pos_ind.status = UNKNOWN
03-31 19:22:13.976      198-198/? I/mm-camera? gyro_module_start_session: Enter
03-31 19:22:13.976      198-198/? I/mm-camera? gyro_module_start_session: Init DSPS
03-31 19:22:13.976      198-198/? I/mm-camera? gyro_module_start_session: Exit successful
03-31 19:22:13.976      198-198/? I/mm-camera? gyro_module_get_port: Exit successful
03-31 19:22:13.976      198-198/? E/mm-camera? cpp_module_start_session:352, info: starting session 1
03-31 19:22:13.996      198-198/? E/mm-camera? cpp_module_start_session:422, info: cpp_thread created.
03-31 19:22:13.996    198-11446/? E/mm-camera? cpp_thread_func:55: cpp_thread entering the polling loop...
03-31 19:22:13.996      198-198/? E/mm-camera? cpp_module_start_session:425, info: session 1 started.
03-31 19:22:13.996      198-198/? E/mm-camera? c2d_module_start_session:246, info: starting session 1
03-31 19:22:13.996    198-11447/? E/mm-camera? c2d_thread_func:39: c2d_thread entering the polling loop...
03-31 19:22:13.996      198-198/? E/mm-camera? c2d_module_start_session:284, info: c2d_thread created.
03-31 19:22:13.996      198-198/? E/mm-camera? c2d_module_start_session:306, info: session 1 started.
03-31 19:22:13.996      198-198/? E/mm-camera-sensor? module_module_set_session_data:2435 max delay 2 report dSelay 1
03-31 19:22:13.996      198-198/? E/mm-camera? module_faceproc_set_session_data:1826] Per frame control 2 1
03-31 19:22:13.996     184-1036/? E/mm-camera-intf? mm_camera_open:  opened, break out while loop
03-31 19:22:13.996     184-1036/? I/Camera2-Parameters? Camera 0: Disabling ZSL mode
03-31 19:22:13.996  10556-10556/com.test.testFlashlight D/Debug_point_2? Turning flashlight on
03-31 19:22:14.006     184-3785/? E/QCamera3HWI? camera_metadata_t* qcamera::QCamera3HardwareInterface::translateCapabilityToMetadata(int): Setting focus mode to auto
03-31 19:22:14.006     184-3785/? E/QCamera3HWI? camera_metadata_t* qcamera::QCamera3HardwareInterface::translateCapabilityToMetadata(int): Setting focus mode to auto
03-31 19:22:14.006  10556-10556/com.test.testFlashlight D/Debug_point_3? Flashlight should be on
03-31 19:22:14.036  10556-10556/com.test.testFlashlight D/dalvikvm? GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 281K, 2% free 16922K/17232K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
03-31 19:22:14.086    1168-1168/? I/WallpaperService? engine paused
03-31 19:22:14.086    1168-1168/? I/AndroidInput? sensor listener tear down
```

I am wondering where I need to focus to allow for the flash to be activated.

Comment: I know another user is having trouble getting the torch mode on Nexus 5 to work. In the following post, at the end of the answer, there is code for the minimum necessary to activate the torch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630453/flash-torch-on-google-nexus-5/22635310  You might try that first.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

For some phones you need a SurfaceView to get the flash. Additionally it may be better to use:

```
    List<String> flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
```

because of the wide variety of devices out there. Flashlights are no fun, my friend.